# Turn Adobe Illustrator Template into Wordpress Theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, adobe-illustrator

Can anyone give me any advice or direct me to a good tutorial on converting an Adobe Illustrator template to a WordPress template?

I've read a lot about doing this by using slices, but I've also heard sites built with slices are a nightmare to maintain. This site will be updated frequently so I can't have that problem. Also, the site's background has a gradient, so I'm not sure how slices would work with that.

If I have to use slices to make this template though I could go with a solid color, but the gradient is preferred.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to break down all of the elements of your illustrator template.  And then build that from the ground up on creating your Wordpress theme.  Since you have a gradient background, slicing it all up would not be the best option.  Take all of the elements of this Illustrator template and save them separately.

Then I would familiarize with the steps on turning these elements into a fully function Wordpress theme

http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/news/building-wordpress-themes-from-scratch-a-new-book-from-one-of-our-wptuts-authors/

Answer (score 1):

Use slices just to cut up your site in a way that allows you to use current CSS techniques. For example, a small slice for a background image that's a seamless pattern, or a thin, tall slice for a vertical gradient (you'd use CSS to repeat-x it across). You'll probably need to hide various layers as you slice to get the right bits and pieces. You've probably read folks who have had issues with the old concept of slicing a design - where the whole site was built on pieced together images, and making edits was a pain as a result.

If you just use slicing to basically grab the individual elements you need (read up on image spites as well for efficiency!) and background images - just the parts you need whereever you can, because you can repeat vertically and horizontally - you'll be just fine.